# Merge multiple files with same name into one file

Tags: java, file-io, merge

So I have been trying to figure out how I can achieve this. I have a file called "part1.txt" which appears in multiple directories. For example, it appears in the directories:

```
 usr/documents/trial/part1.txt

 usr/documents/trial2/part1.txt

 usr/documents/zip/part1.txt
```

Each of these part1.txt files contains a different kind of information. I want to write a java program to merge all of these files into one file. Is there a way that this can be achieved in java? or should I use hadoop to perform such a task? It would be wonderful if someone could tell me how to write this program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by having a look at [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Essentially, you need to do a recursive search of the directories you want to include and append the contents to some other file

For example, you could simply create a `BufferedWriter` which allows you to write content to a, in this case, specific file (or master file)...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File output = new File("Master-Part1.txt");
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(output))) {
        findAndAppend(new File("."), bw);
    } catch (IOException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You need to scan a specific file for any matches (`part1.txt`) and append their contents to the `BufferedWriter`, if found.

Once you've done the current directory, you need to try and scan the sub directories, if any...

```
public static void findAndAppend(File parent, BufferedWriter bw) throws IOException {

    // Find any matching files...  
    File files[] = parent.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            return pathname.getName().equals("part1.txt");
        }
    });

    // Append any results...technically there should only be 0-1 
    // matches, but this is a nice example ;)
    for (File file : files) {
        append(file, bw);
    }

    // Find the sub directories...
    File dirs[] = parent.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            return pathname.isDirectory();
        }
    });

    // Scan the sub directories...
    for (File dir : dirs) {
        findAndAppend(dir, bw);
    }

}
```

Finally, you need to be able to write the content of any matches to your master file...

```
protected static void append(File file, BufferedWriter bw) throws IOException {

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String text = null;
        while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
            bw.write(text);
            bw.newLine();
        }
    } finally {
    }

}
```

This example is using Java 7's [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) functionality, so make sure you're running Java 7.

Take a look at [`java.io.File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) for more details

**Updated with `walkFileTree` example (Java 7)**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File master = new File("Master-part1.txt");
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(master))) {
        Path path = master.toPath();
        Files.walkFileTree(path, new FileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                if (file.toFile().getName().equals("part1.txt")) {
                    append(file.toFile(), bw);
                }
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
}

protected static void append(File file, BufferedWriter bw) throws IOException {

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String text = null;
        while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
            bw.write(text);
            bw.newLine();
        }
    } finally {
    }

}
```

Comment: Why use Java 6 File if you use Java 7?

Comment: @fge Because it's what I'm familiar with and the "path tree walking" does my head in

Comment: Well, I can create a gist for you demonstrating how you can do that with `Files.walkFileTree()` ;)

Comment: @fge I have "used" it before, but this was just quicker to type ;)

Comment: @fge One of the  other reasons I wanted to do it this way was because I could control the order in which things took place, doing all the "file" response first and then the directories second...

Comment: @fge It's also easily translatable back to Java 6 and below ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can look into this:

```
public File mergeFiles(List<File> files,
                       String mergedFileName) {
    File mergedFile = new File(mergedFileName);
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
    try {
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(mergedFile, true);
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (File f : files) {
        FileInputStream fis;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

            String aLine;
            while ((aLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                bufferedWriter.write(aLine);
                bufferedWriter.newLine();
            }

            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        bufferedWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return mergedFile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to do this. You would need to know or search for all versions of the text file with the name you give it and then read each one into the program and then use stringbuilder to create a single string and write that back to a file. Things to think about are if order of merging matters and if you also want to delete the old files you are grabbing from.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a Unix/Linux system. If you are not restricted to Java, please take a look at the `cat` command. Otherwise, the following should work (uses Apache commons):

```
// Files to read
File file1 = new File("usr/documents/trial/part1.txt");
File file2 = new File("usr/documents/trial2/part1.txt");

// File to write
File file3 = new File("concatenated-file.txt");

// Read the file as string
String file1Str = FileUtils.readFileToString(file1);
String file2Str = FileUtils.readFileToString(file2);

// Write the file
FileUtils.write(file3, file1Str);
FileUtils.write(file3, file2Str, true); // true => append mode
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested very large files and it works fine!

```
public static void mergeFiles(List<File> files, File target) {
    OutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(target);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (File f : files) {
        InputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
            int i;
            while ((i = fis.read(buf)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buf, 0, i);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```